# Adding color theme only for a specific language

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am in that lucky case where I am writing both the language syntax (tmLanguage file) and I'd like to write a custom coloring for that as well in my extension.

Is it possible to create a theme which does not interfere with the user's theme, just adds some extra to it? I only need some extra colors, because the common themes aren't colorful enough for my needs.

If I create a new theme I observed that it completely overwrites the previous one and loads specifically mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSCode's builtin Dark+ theme does something like that: [it extends / includes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/6b4d9860a519ca080264d19d5d282ec316f83e18/extensions/theme-defaults/themes/dark_plus.json#L4) the regular Dark theme.

```
"include": "./dark_vs.json"
```

However, I guess this relies on relative file paths and the fact that they are both in the same directory, so you might have to ship copies of the themes with your extension for this to work.